# How to search phonetic misspelled word in Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

Here is the Scenario of Lucene Searching,

In Lucene document contains **two fields having values "Red" and "Red Feather"**.

I want to search **Red Feathar**.

It is returning  **"Red" as first result**. But I want **"Red Feather" as first result**.

I tried using fuzzy query term matches. but its makes my application slow.

So is there any another way to search Phonetic misspelled word in Lucene?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There are [Phonetic matching methods](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/analyzers-phonetic/org/apache/lucene/analysis/phonetic/PhoneticFilter.html) in Lucene, but I think a `FuzzyQuery` is the right choice for this case.  There are a few ways to enhance it's performance:

- Are you using Lucene 4.0 or later?  `FuzzyQuery` performance got a [huge boost in 4.0](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/03/lucenes-fuzzyquery-is-100-times-faster.html).
- Set a [prefixLength](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyQuery.html#FuzzyQuery%28org.apache.lucene.index.Term,%20int,%20int%29).  This forces the first x characters to directly match, which narrows searching for matching terms significantly, and takes better advantage of lucene's indexing methods, leading to significantly improved performance.
- If you are using 3.6 or earlier (and can't switch to a more recent version), make sure you set [`minimumSimilarity`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyQuery.html#FuzzyQuery%28org.apache.lucene.index.Term,%20float%29)
- If you are using 4.0 or later, you could try setting [`maxEdits`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyQuery.html#FuzzyQuery%28org.apache.lucene.index.Term,%20int%29) to 1

Comment: Thanks very much @femtoRgn! I followed your steps and It helps me lot in to enhance Lucene performance..